# Manipulate string in file using shell

Tags: string, bash, shell, file

I'm trying to modify a string in a file using shell script.

What in the file `version.yaml`:

```
Version: 1.0.0-ghjjh
```

What I expect:
Add a suffix `-{given argument}`to the version string given an argument if there is no suffix added yet. Otherwise modify the suffix using the given argument.

For a given argument `0`:
For the above file I provided, there is no suffix, the expected result is `Version: 1.0.0-ghjjh-0`

After this string in the file already has the suffix. Next time for a given argument `6`, the expected result is `Version: 1.0.0-ghjjh-6`

What's the simplest way to do this in shell script?

Comment: Use `sed` with `s/` substitution. Match the version with some regex up until the suffix. Remove the suffix and substitute with a new one.

Comment: Why is `-0` a suffix but `-ghjjh` is not?

Answer (score 0):

Store the version in a separate file and regenerate the YAML from a [template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).